# Returning tuple as a future in scala not working

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to return a tuple from a function as Future in following way:

```
def f:Future[(List[Int],List[String])] = Future{
   (List(1,2,3),List("Hello","World"))
}
```

which i am calling from main as follows:

```
var (a,c) = f
```

This is giving me following error

```
Error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2)
required: scala.concurrent.Future[(List[Int], List[String])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to unpack a tuple, but `f` is a `Future`, not a `Tuple2`.

Try

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val (a, c) = Await.result(f, 1.second)
```

Using `Await.result` will block until `f` is done, then return the tuple inside or throw an exception.

You can also use [`onSuccess`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) if you want to perform a side-effecting callback -

```
f.onSuccess { case (a, c) => println(a, c) }
```

If you want to modify the value but you don't need to return yet, you can transmute the contents while still being wrapped in a future using `map`:

```
def doStuff(a: List[Int], c: List[String]): Int = ???
val g: Future[Int] = f.map(doStuff)
```

<sub>(Also, you should really be structuring your code to use `val` and not `var`)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

The compiler complains that a tuple is expected, however it gets a Future of a tuple as the return type of `f`.
You can use one of the Future combinators in order to work with the value wrapped in the Future. For example you can use `map`:

```
f.map{case (a,c) => do something... }
```

Also, when you just need to return a Future but do not need to perform a computation asynchronously, such as in your case, it is better to use

```
Future.successful((List(1,2,3),List("Hello","World")))
```

that creates an already completed future in order to save overhead of creating / reusing a thread from the thread pool.

Comment: why is the case needed for this map scenario?

Comment: @ChampS The case is not needed but used as convenience to extract the tuple members out. I could have written `f.map{t => do something with t._1 and t._2... }` instead

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `f` as indicated is a `Future` of a `Tuple2`.  Therefore you can't assign a `Tuple2` to the return type.  You can, however, process the results of the `Future` asynchronously:

```
def f:Future[(List[Int],List[String])] = Future{
  (List(1,2,3),List("Hello","World"))
}

f onSuccess { case (a,c) => ...}
```